# How to plot a function as a heat map in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm currently trying to switch to python. At the moment I'm trying to reproduce a graph I plotted with gnuplot (the plot from gnuplot is attached) in python.
[image: Image plotted with gnuplot]
However, when I try to do something similar with python, my plot is completely black. I've looked at similar problems and tried pcolormesh and imshow. Both to the same result. However, there is no error message. Here is my minimal code example:

`

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f(m,p):
    return ((m-1)**2*(1-p)*p)/(1+(m-1)*p)**2

m = np.arange(0.0,10.0,100.0)

p = np.arange(0.0,0.1,1.0)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(m, p)

Z =f(X,Y)

plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)

plt.show()
```

Probably, I'm doing some beginners mistake. But I'm very grateful if somebody could point it out to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the values of `m` and `p`. I guess they are not what you think.

Comment: Agree with @Goyo. m and p seems to be empty. np.arrange(start, end, step)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [numpy.arrange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)

```
 numpy.arange([start, ]stop, [step, ]dtype=None)
```

**step** : number, optional

> Spacing between values. For any output out, this is the distance
>   between two adjacent values, out[i+1] - out[i]. The default step size
>   is 1. If step is specified, start must also be given.

So `np.arange(0.0,10.0,100.0)` equals `[0]`.

And I think maybe this is you want:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(m,p):
    return ((m-1)**2*(1-p)*p)/(1+(m-1)*p)**2
m = np.arange(0.0,100.0,10.0)
p = np.arange(0.0,1.0,0.1)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(m, p)
Z =f(X,Y)
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

And you will get:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, you can use plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z,shading='gouraud') to interpolate and make your plot smooth, like in figure from the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really was a beginner's mistake on my part. I justed assumed it worked the same way as in Matlab. So thanks for pointing it out,